# Allow braces for blocks that return

Tags: ruby, rubocop

When I write a multi-line block that returns a value, I like to use braces instead of `do`-`end` in order to make evident that the purpose of the block is to return things, as opposed to do things.

The standard configuration of Rubocop doesn't allow that, and `rubocop -a` converts any multi-line block in a `do`-`end` block.

```rb
# I like but Rubocop hates.
expect {
  delete :destroy, id: thing.to_param
}.to change(Thing, :count).by(-1)

# I don't like but Rubocop does.
expect do
  delete :destroy, id: thing.to_param
end.to change(Thing, :count).by(-1)

# That, we both like.
before do
  stub_api_calls
  admin_sign_in create(:super_admin)   
end
```

Is there any configuration parameter in Rubocop that allows this distinction?

Edit: Or, at least, that avoids changing the brackets block if there is a dot (.) after the closing bracket.

Comment: Obviously, you cannot let Rubocop distinguish whether the method is intended to return something or do something. That is pragmatic rather than semantic. So all you can do is, if possible, turn off Rubocop's preference of `do` ... `end` for multi-line blocks.

Comment: Well, what Rubocop may easily realise is if there is a dot (`. `) just after the closing bracket.

Comment: What if the block is part of the last expression in a method definition?

Comment: Then I wouldn't care that much to about the do-end block because I am not chaining the return value with the next method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that there's a Cop named [Style/BlockDelimiters](http://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cops_style/#styleblockdelimiters) that does the trick. Configured as *semantic*, it enforces curly braces around functional blocks and do..end around imperative code.

This is what I added to `.rubocop.yml`:

```
# Allow curly braces for functional blocks
BlockDelimiters:
  EnforcedStyle: semantic
```